# javascript create div with unique onclick event

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick, unique

I have managed to create divs (I use css to make them blue circles) dynamically and add unique id attributes dynamically too, I'd like to also add unique onclick events also but I am struggling to manage it.  Here is my JavaScript code followed by the HTML I'm working with:

```
var i = 0;

function addCircles(click) {
  var numberOfCircles = document.getElementById('setSize').value;
  var startFromOne = numberOfCircles + 1 - 81;
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = numberOfCircles;

  for (i = 1; i < startFromOne; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.id = "circle" + i;
    element.className = "circle";
 // element.onclick = attack(key);
    document.getElementById('gamecanvas').appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById("circle" + i).innerHTML = i;
  }
}

function attack(key) {
  if (key === 1) {
    document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor = purple;
  }
/* This is a tester, if circle1 turns purple onclick I'm good to go. */
}
```

I want to be able to click the divs (blue circles) and change their colour.

Comment: Where are you getting the variable `key` from? Also if you write `attack(key)`, it will execute the function, rather than binding it to an event handler.

Comment: You can use `getElementsByClassName('circle')` which creates a NodeList that you can loop through and attach a click event to.

Comment: Try to use "function attack(event)" and then in "event.target" you should have the element that has been clicked and in consecuence in "event.target.id" the id of the element.

Comment: I want to give each div I make onclick="attack(n)"  where n will be increments of 1, so the first div with id="circle1" will have onclick="attack(1)" and then id="circle2" will have onclick="attack(2)" and so on.  :)  Forgive me I'm very new to this!

Answer (score 1):

This will assign the `doAttack()` function to all your elements with the class `circle`. Then we just change the color of the circle inside the function!

```js
var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');

for ( var x in circles ) {
    circles[x].onclick = doAttack;   
}

function doAttack() {
    this.style.background = 'purple';
}
```

### Edit

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1cpzt53/2/)

If you wish to do an if statement inside your function just compare the `this.id` to whatever you want. `if ( this.id === 'circle1' ) { .. }`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add an onclick event to the main div:

```
<div onclick="doAttack(event)">
    <div class="circle" id="circle1">
    </div>
    <div class="circle" id="circle2">
    </div>
    <div class="circle" id="circle3">
    </div>
    <div class="circle" id="circle4">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in your *doAttack* function:

```
function doAttack(event) {
    document.getElementById(event.target.id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```